# Clean Python Scrapy Output

Tags: python, csv, xpath, scrapy, output

I need help cleaning Python Scrapy output. I have the following simple spider which fetches the content of an element.

```
class ScrapyscrapSpider (BaseSpider) :
  name = "ss"
  allowed_domains = ["purecss.io"]
  start_urls = ['http://purecss.io/tables/']

  def parse(self, response) :
    sel = Selector (response)
    item = ScrapscrapyItem ()
    item['Heading'] = str (sel.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/h1').extract ())
    item['Content'] = str (sel.xpath ('//table[@class = "pure-table"]//tr[1]/td[2]').extract ())
    item['Source_Website'] = "http://purecss.io"
    return item
```

**Command**:

```
scrapy crawl ss -o data.csv -t csv
```

**Output**:

```
Content,Heading,Source_Website
"[u'<td>Honda</td>', u'<td>Honda</td>']",,
```

I just want "Honda" to be printed to the csv file and everything else deleted.

extract ()[1] still gives me "[u'Honda', u'Honda']",,

Comment: `.extract()` returns a list, get the first element of the list.

Comment: extract ()[1] still gives me "[u'<td>Honda</td>', u'<td>Honda</td>']",,

Comment: Update your question

Comment: I think you should include more code. working with snippets is fine sometime but your snippet does not produce your output.

Comment: sel.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/h1/text()').extract ()[0]

Answer (score 2):

you can make xpath as follow

```
item['Heading'] = str (sel.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/h1/text()').extract ())
item['Content'] = str (sel.xpath ('//table[@class = "pure-table"]//tr[1]/td[2]/text()').extract ())
```